# Chrome Notifications are not 'notifying'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flask, notifications, google-chrome-devtools

```js
setTimeout(function(){chrome.notifications.create({
    type: "basic",
    title: "Test Notification",
    message: "testing"
});
},5000);
```

I'm trying to make a notification after 5 seconds after the page loads but it doesn't give a notification at all.

There is a TypeError that comes up but I don't understand why `chrome.notifications` would be `undefined`. How do I fix this and make it work?

I made this script after looking [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#method-create).

**EDIT:** This may help? I'm using flask and I'm hoping to do it like this.

Comment: `chrome.notifications` is only for chrome apps/extensions.

Comment: @wOxxOm But How would I make one otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking into the wrong documentation. Link which you posted is the documentation for apps/browser extensions which you can download from the [google web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?hl=en-GB). This is proper [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) for your purpose. Btw, don't forget to ask for permission first, otherwise, your notification will not have a chance to fire! Wish you best luck with hacking ;)

P.S. Code snippet to try in browser

```
function notifyMe() {
  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
    Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }

  // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you 
  // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
}
```

Edits at 02.07.2020
Code snippet which I provided above will not request permission once again in case you have denied it previously. It means, if you open a console on StackOverflow, where you previosly denied access to notifications and after you try it here then you will see no result at all. This snippet will request to make a notification and will not care do you have it denied previously or not

```js
function notifyMe() {
 if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
  } else {
    Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I placed it into my `<script>` tag in my HTML file and then refreshed the page but I didn't get a single alert and I didn't get an error. Notifications weren't given either. What happened?

Comment: However, I do know that the function is called.

Comment: @12944qwerty put function in a browser and call it after 
function notifyMe(){ /* ... */};
notifyMe();

You should see permission request in top left corner of browser

Comment: I had done that, but it didn't work. No errors and no alerts and notifications or request.